# Не удаётся импортировать библиотеку uno в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, open-office, uno

Когда я пытаюсь подключить библиотеку uno:

```
import uno
```

выводит ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/uno/__init__.py", line 
4, in <module>
    from base import Element, Css, Payload, UnoBaseFeature, 
UnoBaseField
ImportError: cannot import name 'Element'
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Причем файл `base.py`, который находится в той же папке, где и `__init__`, содержит класс `Element`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по метке openoffice в вопросе, вам скорее всего нужен не пакет [uno](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uno) (описание: "Extremely fast and easy feature based HTML generator"), а пакет [unotools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unotools) (описание: "Interacting with OpenOffice.org/LibreOffice using UNO").

Соответственно, первый устанавливается командой `pip install uno`, а
второй - `pip install unotools`, хотя после установки и импортируется одинаково - через `import uno`.

Ошибка в вопросе связана с тем, что пакет uno писался под Python2, а под Python3 не тестировался (об этом говорят, например, вызовы `print` без скобок в коде библиотеки).